# I am working on a django website and having trouble in calling a function at the correct place

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a checkout form on my django website:`<form class="row contact_form" action="." method="post" id="form">`. That form has a submit button at the end:`<input id="form-button" class="btnabc btnabc-outline-info btnabc-lg" type="submit" value="Continue to Payment">`
On clicking this button I want to redirect the user to the payment gateway and if his transaction is successful I want to save his information that he entered in the form:

This is the javascript code for the button:

```
document.getElementById('payment-info').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      submitFormData()
    })

    function submitFormData() {
      console.log('Payment Button Clicked')
      var userFormData = {
        'name': null,
      }

      var shippingInfo = {
        'address': null,
      }

      shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
      userFormData.name=form.name.value

      var url = "/process_order/"
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'form': userFormData, 'shipping': shippingInfo }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
          alert('Transaction Completed')
          window.location.href = "{% url 'index' %}"
        })    
    }
```

This is my views.py:

```
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        total=float(data['form']['total'])
        order.transaction_id=transaction_id

        if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.complete = True
        order.save()
    

        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            state=data['shipping']['state'],
            zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
            name=data['form']['name'],
            email=data['form']['email'],
            mobile=data['form']['mobile'],
        )

        param_dict = {

                'MID': 'DIY12386817555501617',
                'ORDER_ID': str(order.id),
                'TXN_AMOUNT': '4',
                'CUST_ID': 'j',
                'INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID': 'Retail',
                'WEBSITE': 'WEBSTAGING',
                'CHANNEL_ID': 'WEB',
                'CALLBACK_URL':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/handlerequest/',

        }
        param_dict['CHECKSUMHASH'] = Checksum.generate_checksum(param_dict, MERCHANT_KEY)
        return render(request, 'paytm.html', {'param_dict': param_dict})

    return HttpResponse('Done')


@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    # paytm will send you post request here
    form = request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            print('order successful')
        else:
            print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
    
    return render(request, 'paymentstatus.html', {'response': response_dict})
```

This handlerequest function is basically for checking if the transaction is verified or not.

This is my **paytm.html**

```
<form action="https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction" method="post" name="paytm">
        {% for key,value in param_dict.items %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{key}}" value="{{value}}">
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    document.paytm.submit()
</script>
```

Currently whenever I click on the payment button it just saves the information of the form (submitformdata() in javascript) without verifying the transaction and also i am not taken to the payment page where the user can pay.

The error is with the place where I am calling the submitformdata function and I cant figure out a way to call that function only when the transaction is verified. Please help me figuring out a way to do so. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: so your problem is how to get access or call to handle request function isn't it?

Comment: the place where I am calling the submitformdata function and I cant figure out a way to call that function only when the transaction is verified. Please help me out

Comment: so you want to save that data only and only the trasaction is verified true .but in the reality you save any order with transaction pending and save all the data with pending and now the work for callback url of paytm paytm will call that function url from that automatically and request to that handle request so from that your order is verified and you can change that transaction to complete so you can get order id in the callback url and make that order to complete

Comment: you have to save order first after that you can change the order state

Comment: one more thing why you use ajax method you can do this with simple form post method as far as i know you can specify you all logic in the post method of the form what you put in process order function

Comment: Can you rather tell the code where I am going wrong and tell what needs to be done please

Comment: By not using ajax do you mean that I can simply take the form data and post it in the database.Yes that is an option but in that too I cannot figure out what to do with order and how to save it only when the transaction has been made

Comment: use your own way where you are confortable.

Answer (score 0):

actually the reason is when you try to implement this you haven't put this in the server right now so the paytm cant get access to the callback url for transaction verification just like i cant able to access 127.0.0.1:8000 from my laptop right now so you have to deploy that app so there is one thing you can do is use 'pagekite.net' and you get run temparary app on that url and make call back url accorging to that

Comment: No that is not the case. I have seen several tutorials where we can access through localhost only.

Comment: can you give me the link where you seen tutorial actually it is not possible

Comment: https://www.codewithharry.com/videos/python-django-tutorials-hindi-66  check this one out.

Comment: I want to workout a way from my code in which when a user clicks on payment button he is first redirected to payment page and he completed the transaction and if the transaction is successful then his data is saved. Currently with the code it doesnt redirect and saves the data and that is becoz of my submitformdata function in javascript. I need to place it at a place where I can see if the transaction was successful but i cant figure out that place

Comment: technically its not possible because callback response is made from paytm and its also stores its predefined value look 39:30 first three line so how you will know what order contains and what is not so you have to have save the order but you can change order status in the handler function

Comment: Yes that is there in my paytm.html already.Check my paytm.html in my code above and also the predefined values is in param_dict and respcodes and responses

Comment: In my param_dict i have set orderid to my order.id

Comment: absolutely right but you will get order id when you save any order isnt it

Comment: but the order is already created. I have used                                                          
order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)   this is my cart view and category view.

Comment: so what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: your question fourth line 'I want to save his information that he entered in the form' you cant because it is a redirected url you have to have save the data when you create order.

Comment: Can you tell the change that I have to make in my code

Comment: you have already saved your shipping address in views.py so everything is working as it need to be

Comment: if you need to add any extra data that you can do that below shipping.objects.create() above or below in views.py

Comment: and what to do for redirecting to payment page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219289/discussion-between-vatsal-jain-and-kishan-parmar).